# Is there an API available on OSM stack that will reliably return the bounding box coordinates of any POI location?

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there an API available on OSM stack that will reliably return the bounding box coordinates of any POIs locations? Something similar to nominatim search but more reliable?

I am already aware of nominatim search API, but on thins API I've noticed that the bounding box is not always set correctly, often the values in this field, are representing a single point, even if the POI location is a rectangle.
eg: boundingbox="46.3704492,46.3705492,-72.5222107,-72.5221107"

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Super+C&addressdetails=1&limit=10000&format=xml&countrycodes=ca

Thanks